# Getting a 403 error with a PPA

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, updates

Why am I getting this 403 error?

```
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
  403  Forbidden
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That PPA has no packages.  Until there's a directory structure created for the repository (which happens when the PPA gets uploads made to it and packages built), Apache will default to 403 Forbidden on PPA repository pages when you try and access that directory tree.  Deletion of all packages in the repo does the same thing, and i think that's waht happened here, given the PPA's description as follows:

> This PPA has been removed from public access as part of a protest
>   against the abuse of open-source projects by large companies. For more
>   detail visit the main page here: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf
>
> If you are a company and you would like this PPA to continue then let
>   me know your preferred route for contributions and I will arrange
>   something.
>
> If we have already been in contact then ping me your Launchpad ID and
>   I will add you to a private PPA in the meantime.
>
> ---
>
> Donate to Python: https://www.python.org/psf/donations/ Donate to
>   Debian: https://www.debian.org/donations Donate to me:
>   https://ko-fi.com/jonathonf

If you need a Python 3.6 environment, your only options really remaining are to compile from source, or compile from source and execute from within your own home environment using a utility such as [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) which allows you to install Python versions that are divergent from what's on your system out of your home directory thereby not messing with system Python packages at all.

(I do not have any affiliation with PyEnv but I find their tool to be extremely useful for using multiple Python versions without touching my system-installed Python versions - and because it's in my home directory it doesn't affect system packages nor need `sudo` or similar elevated privs.  You need build dependencies for the Python 3 packages to build Python, but that's trivial to install and would then Just Work when using the alternative Python environments that PyEnv can let you use in your shell environment (or directly execute))

Comment: How do I remove this ppa?

Comment: @user9042093 You can start by running `grep -r jonathonf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and get a list of files containing that PPA line.  You can then delete all of the filenames listed by `grep` (first bit of the line) with `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/FILENAME` and then run `sudo apt update` again.  The 403s should then go away.  Similar to how https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists has answers for removing 404ing PPAs, the process there works too.